# What is the default app heap size on ICS (Android OS4.0)?

Tags: android

I'm trying to make my app ICS-compatible and I'm getting OutOfMemoryErrors that I never got with 2.3.3 and earlier. I don't own an ICS device so I'm using the emulator and I noticed the default heap size is 24M, which is the same as previous versions (on the emulator).

Is 24M the default heap size on actual devices? What about the Google Nexus?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

I did not find the exact size, in fact it is likely different on different devices, but I can confirm it's bigger than 24Mb after I tested my app on a Google Nexus and didn't get any OOM errors. The emulator probably defaults to 24Mb for all OS versions.

Comment: is this right info " The emulator probably defaults to 24Mb for all OS versions." ?